# inkscape python how get coordonate of selected node

Tags: python, inkscape

How can I get the coordinates of a selected point of a path? I want to try to join two nodes of two paths by line (same as the image below), but I can't find a function can get coordinates of a selected node of the path!

So user select two node of different paths and program join by a line!

[this image describe what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YatCx.jpg)

If the user selects two nodes of different paths, the I want the program to be able to join them with a line.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For getting node coordinates, here's a demo extension:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/171640/ (on the right, in the 'Bug attachments' section)

It still works with Inkscape 1.0.x, but gives a couple deprecation warnings.
See https://inkscape.gitlab.io/extensions/documentation/ for upcoming API and https://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Release_notes/1.0#For_extension_writers for more general info about upcoming changes.

Comment: I have inkscape 0.92 and example working perfectly! thanks a lot!